# Problems with spatial autocorrelation in Geographically Weighted Regression (GWR) analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics, autocorrelation

I have conducted an **[Ordinary Least Squares](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/How_OLS_regression_works/005p0000002z000000/)** (OLS) and [**Geographically Weighted Regression**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005p00000031000000) (GWR) analysis in ArcGIS where I have tried to predict biodiversity patterns in an area. When I examine the results with **Spatial Autocorrelation** the residuals tends to be clustered with a fairly high Z-value.

The result from the GWR, however, tends to be the expected when I visualize it. How do I handle the clustering? What problems does it creates, IS there any problems?

Comment: Could you please clarify what it means to "examine the results with spatial autocorrelation" and how that indicates clustering of the residuals?  Showing a small example might help.

Comment: Well, I followed the Esri tutorial on GWR and it seems to be recommended to check the result from the std residuals with spatial autocorrelation in order to see if they tend to be clustered, random or dispersed.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you have computed a measure of clustering of the GWR residuals and it appears to indicate clustering.  What happens when you decrease the size of the local neighborhood used in GWR?  Does the clustering appear to be reduced?

Comment: Well, yes. If I decrease the size of the local neighborhood, the clustering appears to be reduced, that´s correct. The problem is, however, that when I decrease the number of neighbours the GWR doesn´t seem to produce a full-scale analysis and it produces blanks among the polygon. Um, do you understand?

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected. It indicates you might not have sufficient data density in order to carry out GWR. It's not possible to recommend alternatives without knowing why you're performing GWR, what you hope to achieve with it, and the nature of your data.

Comment: Allright, well i´m investigating different ecosystem services in an area, and how they correlate to biodiversity. The data consists of a polygon shapefile where the attribute table includes biodiversity and other ecosystem services such as carbon sequestration in soils, recreation, or stocks of certain herbs and berries, and so on. Each field is rated from one to ten depending on the ecosystem service significance. Would you recommend me to use another method?

Comment: And does the fact that it is clustered necessarily pose any problem?